# Method Login always return false using Android Retrofit2

Tags: java, android

I've wrote Java code on Android Studio.  I've made Login method and something happened within my code. It hadn't return proper return value.  The Return Value always False.  While I've checked with `LogD` function on Android Studio, the Boolean variable has been changed properly but It has changed again in the end of method so the Login method always return false & I can't proceed to login.

Please help me to resolve this confusing moment.  Any answer will be appreciated, Thanks a bunch.

```
public class AppLogin {

    UniversalResponse uniresp = new UniversalResponse();
    private Boolean hasil = true ;

    public Boolean getHasil() {
        return hasil;
    }

    public void setHasil(Boolean hasil) {
        this.hasil = hasil;
    }
    
    public Boolean authorize(String user, String passwd){
        APIInterface apiInterface;
        LoginModel logindata = new LoginModel();
        logindata.setUsername(user);
        logindata.setPassword(passwd);

        apiInterface = APIClient.getClient().create(APIInterface.class);

        //Call<UniversalResponse> call = apiInterface.doLogin(logindata.getUsername(), logindata.getPassword());
        Call<UniversalResponse> call = apiInterface.doLogin(user, passwd);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<UniversalResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UniversalResponse> call, Response<UniversalResponse> response)
            {
                UniversalResponse uniresp = response.body();
                Log.d("Login Module - Value dr Hasil sebelum Reponse Successfull" , getHasil().toString());
                if(response.isSuccessful() ) {
                    Log.d("Nama Service", uniresp.getService());
                    Log.d("Isi Message", uniresp.getMessage());
                    Log.d("Login Module - Value dr Hasil di DALAM Reponse Successfull" , getHasil().toString());
                    if ( uniresp.getMessage().equals("Success") && uniresp.getService().equals("MobileAppLogin") )
                    {
                        setHasil(true);
                        Log.d("Login Module - Value dr Hasil di DALAM Reponse Successfull dlm If Getmessasge Equals" , getHasil().toString());
                    }
                    else {  setHasil(false);
                    Log.d("Login Module - Value dr Hasil di DALAM Reponse Successfull dlm If Getmessasge Equals Equals ELSE Section" , getHasil().toString());   }

                }
                Log.d("Login Module - Value dr Hasil di LUAR Reponse Successfull" , getHasil().toString());

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UniversalResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                call.cancel();
                hasil= false;
            }
        });

        Log.i("Login Module - Value dr Hasil di DEKAT RETURN PALING BAWAH" , getHasil().toString());

       return getHasil();

    }


}
```

Comment: can you paste the full log that you get? being able to see the sequence of your log will be helpful to find the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the way you wrote your code won't always work. This is the classic case of an asynchronous task being run as a synchronous one.

The value of `hasil` is changed inside `onFailure` and `onResponse` which may not have a chance to finish before you return from the method `authorize`.

You need to change the way you're propagating the value of `hasil` to the calling code in order to be able to get this to work. There are several ways of doing so, one easy way without introducing too many changes to your code is to have a callback:

```
interface Callback {
  void onResponse(boolean hasil);

  void onError(Throwable t);
}
```

Now instead of returning from the fuction `authorize` you need to pass this callback in:

```
public void authorize(String user, String passwd, Callback callback){
   // ...
   call.enqueue(new Callback<UniversalResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<UniversalResponse> call, Response<UniversalResponse> response)
        {
           if(response.isSuccessful() ) {
                if ( uniresp.getMessage().equals("Success") && uniresp.getService().equals("MobileAppLogin") )
                {
                    callback.onResponse(true);
                }
                else {  callback.onResponse(false);  }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<UniversalResponse> call, Throwable t) {
           callback.onError(t);
        }
    });
}
```

The idea is to not return anything and let whoever is calling your code get notified of the result of the login operation when the login operation fails or succeeds. Notice, this is exactly how you've implemented your retrofit call with `call.enqueue`.

As I mentioned, there are other ways to deal with this. I think this one is potentially the one that introduces fewer changes.